# Combining two SQL result to form one result set in a row with different column names

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

As I need to combine two SQL results forming one row in the result set.

I tried to make use of `union` function. But results in two row in the result set  with `oponent_*` column leaving `opposer_*` column completely. But it should include both the column in the result set. Here is the below piece of code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `team_member`.`Team_ID` AS oponent_Team_ID,
  `team`.`Founder_ID` AS oponent_Founder_ID,
  `team`.`Team_Logo` AS oponent_Team_Logo,
  `team`.`team_Name` AS oponent_Founder_ID,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` AS oponent_team_1_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` AS oponent_team_2_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_time` AS oponent_game_time,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS oponent_game_date,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS oponent_game_name,
  `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS oponent_accept
FROM
  `team_member`
  JOIN `team`
    ON `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `team`.`Team_ID`
  JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
WHERE `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` = '11'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
  `team_member`.`Team_ID` AS opposer_Team_ID,
  `team`.`Founder_ID` AS opposer_Founder_ID,
  `team`.`Team_Logo` AS opposer_Team_Logo,
  `team`.`team_Name` AS opposer_Founder_ID,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` AS opposer_team_1_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` AS opposer_team_2_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_time` AS opposer_game_time,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS opposer_game_date,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS opposer_game_name,
  `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS opposer_accept
FROM
  `team_member`
  JOIN `team`
    ON `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `team`.`Team_ID`
  JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
WHERE `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` = '11'
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| oponent_Team_ID | oponent_Founder_ID | oponent_Team_Logo | oponent_Founder_ID | oponent_team_1_id | oponent_team_2_id | oponent_game_time | oponent_game_date | oponent_game_name | oponent_accept |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|               4 |                  1 | 486396439.png     | Nish               |                11 |                 4 | 1:30am            | 2019-06-28        | Battlefield 4     |              0 |
|              13 |                  7 | 557132285.png     | BFM                |                13 |                11 | 1:30am            | 2019-07-12        | FIFA 17           |              1 |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| oponent_Team_ID | oponent_Founder_ID | oponent_Team_Logo | oponent_team_Name  | oponent_team_1_id | oponent_team_2_id | oponent_game_time | oponent_game_date | oponent_game_name | oponent_accept | opposer_Team_ID | opposer_Founder_ID | opposer_Team_Logo | opposer_team_Name  | opposer_team_1_id | opposer_team_2_id | opposer_game_time | opposer_game_date | opposer_game_name | opposer_accept |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|               4 |                  1 | 486396439.png     | Team 1             |                11 |                 4 | 1:30am            | 2019-06-28        | Battlefield 4     |              0 |              13 |                  7 | 557132285.png     | Team 3             |                13 |                11 | 1:30am            | 2019-07-12        | FIFA 17           |              1 |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a88e0d/2)

Required to obtain result with one row combined with different column names in the result set. Let me know are there any other functions apart from it.

Comment: Finally, [Expected Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3021ad94394ad9779db35d05027efe9) turns out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `case when`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=660fd78fa9d8a846879a7ca7df88fd83)**

```
select max(case when flag=1 then   oponent_Team_ID end) as oponent_Team_ID,
max(case when flag=0 then   oponent_Team_ID end) as opposer_Team_ID

from
(
SELECT DISTINCT
  `team_member`.`Team_ID` AS oponent_Team_ID,
  `team`.`Founder_ID` AS oponent_Founder_ID,
  `team`.`Team_Logo` AS oponent_Team_Logo,
  `team`.`team_Name` AS oponent_Founder_Name,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` AS oponent_team_1_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` AS oponent_team_2_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_time` AS oponent_game_time,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS oponent_game_date,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS oponent_game_name,
  `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS oponent_accept, 1 as flag
FROM
  `team_member`
  JOIN `team`
    ON `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `team`.`Team_ID`
  JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
WHERE `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` = '11'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
  `team_member`.`Team_ID` AS opposer_Team_ID,
  `team`.`Founder_ID` AS opposer_Founder_ID,
  `team`.`Team_Logo` AS opposer_Team_Logo,
  `team`.`team_Name` AS opposer_Founder_ID,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` AS opposer_team_1_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` AS opposer_team_2_id,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_time` AS opposer_game_time,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS opposer_game_date,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS opposer_game_name,
  `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS opposer_accept,0
FROM
  `team_member`
  JOIN `team`
    ON `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `team`.`Team_ID`
  JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON `teams_game_match`.`team_1_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
WHERE `teams_game_match`.`team_2_id` = '11'
)A
```

Comment: @Nishanthॐ, check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=660fd78fa9d8a846879a7ca7df88fd83

Comment: [Check Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=702789a7d3b2434a6eb16e766a18e03d) Getting Error as `Unknown column 'opposer_team_1_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Nishanthॐ, chk now - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a78d7ac7b2ac2bcab2964eb3b379a644 when you do union then no need to define column name for 2nd query, so that's why it was giving error